# VBScript to VB error

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I have been rewriting some of my old VBscript code to VB code.I am almost done with everything but I get an error at one place.

VB Script

```
Session("FirstName") = Request.Cookies("FirstName").Item
```

VB

```
Session.Add("FirstName", Request.Cookies("FirstName").Item)
```

and the error is

```
BC30455: Argument not specified for parameter 'key' of 'Public Default Property Item(key As String) As String'.
```

Can anybody tell me how to correct this error or atleast what does the error mean?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    Session.Add("FirstName", Request.Cookies("FirstName"))
```

should work , when you use `.Item`  it is expecting a key for Item such as:

```
Session.Add("FirstName", Request.Cookies("FirstName").Item("ItemKey"))
```